# how to insert dataframe into SQl server database in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I would like to insert entire row from a dataframe into sql server in pandas.

I can insert using below command , how ever, I have 46+ columns and do not want to type all 46 columns.

```
    server = 'server' 
    database = 'db'  
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)
        cnxn.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

is there a way I can insert entire row without giving column names ?
something like this?

```
insert into table1
select * from df
```

I tried below command and it is failing,

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Staging select row"
                   )
Error:('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'row'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. (213)")
```

I cant use to_sql as I cannot import sqlalchemy in UAT or prod.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Along with below statement mention column names

insert into table1 (col1,col2,...conN)
select col1,col2,..colN from df

Ignore Identity columns

Comment: i do not wish to mention column names,, i have 46+ columns. i want to insert all columns at once without specifying individual columns

Comment: in that case target table should not have identity column

Comment: it does not have any key column.